# Disable CSRF protection in websockets using XML configuration

Tags: java, spring, configuration, websocket, csrf-protection

I want to disable websocket CSRF protection using Spring XML configuration.

I know that it can be done [using Java configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-sameorigin-disable):

> ```
> @Configuration
> public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
>
>     ...
>
>     @Override
>     protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
>         return true;
>     }
> }
> ```

… but how can I do the same thing in XML configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put it as an attribute on your websocket-message-broker element:

```
<websocket-message-broker same-origin-disabled="true">...</websocket-message-broker>
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use XML configuration file and add:

```
<http>
  <!-- ... -->
  <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>
```

It is equivalent of java:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
  .csrf().disable();
}
```

Comment: I believe the Asker was interested in web socket security rather than http security